# Using a HTML select element to add get parameters to URL

Tags: html, html-select

I'm on a page like `/gallery.php?place=300&name=place1`, and I want it so that when I submit this form it goes to `/gallery.php?place=300&name=place1&tag=X`, where X is the number of the tag selected.

What's wrong here?

```
<form action="/gallery.php?place=300&name=place1" method="get">
    <select name="tag">
        <option value=1>Aerial</option>
        <option value=2>Autumn</option>
        <option value=4>Boats</option>
        <option value=6>Buildings</option>
        <option value=7>Canals</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hidden` inputs instead of trying to use the query string twice:

```
<form action="/gallery.php" method="get">
    <select name="tag">
        <option value=1>Aerial</option>
        <option value=2>Autumn</option>
        <option value=4>Boats</option>
        <option value=6>Buildings</option>
        <option value=7>Canals</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="place" value="300" />
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="place1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>
```

Using a form with method `get` was overwriting the query string in your form `action`.

Comment: Ah, there you go. I think I must have used POSTs before. Why is the hard stuff easy today, and the easy stuff hard!?

Comment: Yeah, that must be the case. It would work as you had it with a `POST` form.

Answer (score 0):

This extra parameters seem to work for me locally when using "post" instead of "get." Is that it?